# When to use "in the vicinity", "in your vicinity" and "in the vicinity of"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

When we say "in the vicinity" do we mean in the vicinity of the person who said it, or is it an implied location, which is more general? I am asking, because the idiom is "in the vicinity of something" and I am not sure if you can say "in my vicinity", "in your vicinity", "in the vicinity" etc.

For example:

> Check your vicinity for coins.
>
> Check the vicinity for the suspect.

Comment: I am not aware of *in the vicinity of something* being an idiom. The use of *vicinity* is given by its [dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vicinity), where it's just a word used in a sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not an idiom. It is strange to say "check your vicinity for coins" because it is rather technical language and "looking around for coins" is not a technical subject.

This word is used more frequently to describe larger areas. Context tells you what it refers to.

"In my vicinity" is around me.

"In its vicinity" is around it.

"In the vicinity of" is around a noun.